# How can I use the Secondary Images Upload Metabox from Woocommerce on a Custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type, image-gallery

Woocommerce comes with the metabox for multiple images upload called Product Image Gallery.

Those are secondary images.

How can I use it on a custom post type?

[image: Product Image Gallery example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install the following Plugin
   [Featured Galleries](https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-galleries/)
2. Now edit the file controller.php
3. This file is located at

   Your-wordpress-installation/wp-content/plugins/featured-galleries/includes
4. Replace the following code

   apply_filters( 'fg_post_types', [ 'post', 'page' ] );
5. with

   apply_filters( 'fg_post_types', [ 'post', 'page','your_post_type' ] );
6. If you have too many post types

   apply_filters( 'fg_post_types', [ 'post', 'page','your_post_type_1','your_post_type_2','your_post_type_2' ] );
7. Note : replace your_post_type with your post_type